# No resource found in xml android studio

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\yousuf files\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0_rc2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

please resolve this query

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: add build.gradle file to the question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to target sdk 23 which doesn't support this style for buttons. Either don't target sdk 23 or create a values-23 folder and styles file for v23 that doesn't extend this style.